# Django keep history of changes of one field in a JSONField

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model that looks like this:

```
class Order(models.Model):

    ORDER_STATES = (
        ('PAYMENT_IN_PROCCESS', _(u'payment_in_process')),
        ('PAYMENT_REJECTED', _(u'payment_rejected')),
        ('PAYMENT_ACCEPTED', _(u'payment_accepted')),        
    )


    state = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True, choices=ORDER_STATES, default='PAYMENT_IN_PROCCESS', db_index=True)
    history = JSONField(default=[], null=True, blank=True)
    ....

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Order, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.__actual_state = self.state  # important to keep self.history

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print("self.__actual_state: %s" % self.__actual_state)
        print("self.state: %s" % self.state)
        if self.state != self.__actual_state:
            # The state changed, change history
            actual_history = self.history
            print("actual_history: %s" % actual_history)
            new_history = actual_history.append({"state": self.state, "date": datetime.today()})
            print("new_history: %s" % new_history)
            self.history = new_history
        super(Order, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

All I'm trying to do is append the new state (if it changed) to the data kept in the history `JSONField`. However, `new_history` prints `None` I don't know why.

Comment: what's this jsonfield you are using? third party or django.contrib

Comment: @e4c5 django.contrib

Comment: but that doesn't have an append method does it?

Comment: @e4c5 no it doesn't, but a list has. And I'm storing a list there.. anyway if it doesn't have an append method ... why doesn't it give me an error?. All I get is None.

Comment: Have you considered using [django-reversion](https://github.com/etianen/django-reversion) rather than rolling your own implementation for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`append` doesn't return anything, it modifies the target `list` in place.  To do what you wanted you would have to do this:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    import copy
    print("self.__actual_state: %s" % self.__actual_state)
    print("self.state: %s" % self.state)
    if self.state != self.__actual_state:
        # The state changed, change history
        actual_history = self.history
        print("actual_history: %s" % actual_history)
        new_history = copy.copy(actual_history)
        new_history.append({"state": self.state, "date": datetime.today()})
        # of course, you can also just do
        # self.history.append(...) instead of copying and copying back
        print("new_history: %s" % new_history)
        self.history = new_history
    super(Order, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 1):

**from_db vs __init__**

Over riding the [from_db](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/instances/) method instead of the `__init__` method gives greater control, when keeping track of the data that was read in from the database. This is because the `__init__` method will be called even when a new instance is created (rather than been read in from the database). In this case there isn't any history to be saved.

> The from_db() method can be used to customize model instance creation
>   when loading from the database.

**Use of JSONField**

> jsonb data is stored in a decomposed binary format that makes it
>   slightly slower to input due to added conversion overhead, but
>   significantly faster to process, since no reparsing is needed
>   from: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-json.html

Unless you will be reading this archived data very often, use of JSON is just adding an unwanted overhead.

**update and delete**

If you save history as part of the record itself, you are going to lose it when the record is deleted.

Also bear in mind that the save method will not be called if you do something like this:

```
Order.objects.filter(something=something).update(state='new state')
```

so you are going to lose a part of the history.

**Recommended solution to the real problem.**

You are using postgresql, it has wonderfull support for [triggers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-createtrigger.html) and rules. It can help you easily maintain a history and do it faster and more accurately.

This as [drew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1816093/drew) would say is the solution to your [real problem (X)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). The question you have asked is about the problem in you attempted solution (Y) to the real problem (X).

**The solution to the problem in your save method**

As pointed out in the other answer as well, append does not return a value, that's why history is None